# default values in javascript template strings

Tags: javascript, template-strings

Is there any way to access the javascript template-string engine to provide default values for undefined variables?

```
console.log(`this variable is undefined: ${x}`) 
// throws ReferenceError

// but i want to generate something like this:
"this variable is undefined: <warning! undefined variable>"
```

This would be ok, too:

```
function tag(strings,...values){
   // values[i] should be "undefined" if this variable is undefined
}
tag`${x}`
```

If thats not possible, is there a template string engine that does exactly what javascript does and has this feature?

Comment: It's not called a "template string engine", it's just a *template engine*. Go for it.

Comment: String interpolation does not solve reference errors. Why do you have code where `x` is sometimes defined and sometimes not?

Comment: @Bergi because i'm writing a code-generator

Comment: Wouldn't you just put the x in the generated code there?

Comment: no because the user may define the template string

Comment: But the `x` is not part of the template string? Yes, it really sounds like you are looking for a template engine and not for arbitrary string interpolation (where the user writes JS code).

Comment: could it be, that writing a backtick string which contains an `${x}` for example isnt actually defining a string that contains an x but rather gets converted to `"... " + x + "..."` or something similar before it gets interpreted by javascript? therefore there is no actual function in javascript that can do this.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what template literals do: string interpolation. The `x` is an arbitrary JavaScript expression, not "a name".

Comment: @tino We could do `this variable is undefined: ${x = null }` but am afraid it will convert x as a scope variable outside the string

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `||` to coalasce the value, like:

```
console.log(`this variable is undefined: ${x || '<warning! undefined variable>'}`)
```

Comment: The code in the question threw a `ReferenceError` because `x` was never defined. Your code will do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, this also throws a `ReferenceError` - also this would mean i'd have to change the template string, which is not optimal

Comment: How to fix this ReferenceError? It is throwing the same error even if I define variable x: (var x = "test;)

Comment: `\`${typeof greeting === 'undefined' ? 'Howdy' : greeting} there\``

Comment: Sometimes, the simple way is there, in front of our eyes, we just don't see it :)